# programmatically renaming excel worksheet without API

Tags: c++, excel, libxml2

I am working on a project that does not depend on any MS API for open xml documents manipulation (this not a subject of change).

I need to be able to rename a sheet name in a arbitrary excel file.

Can somebody refer me to a page where all the possible references of a worksheet name are listed.

Answer (score 1):

If your programming environment is Excel VBA, then your macro could:

1. open the arbitrary file
2. re-name the worksheet
3. save the arbitrary file
4. close the arbitrary file

For example:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\TestFolder\ABC.xls"
    Sheets(1).Name = "NewName"
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: This obviously depends not only on MS APIs but on MS Office itself. I have to do this literally in the xml presentation of the document.

Comment: That is why I mentioned the programming environment!!  Do you want a simple C program to read the xml as text and convert the worksheet name?  What are you using as your programmable editor?

Comment: I am using c++ and the project is multi-platform, hence the limitation of not using API(s). I am using libxml2 ... the xml parsing is not a problem. The problem is that there is no clear protocol that specifies which attributes or text element could be including a reference of a cell (that might include a worksheet name) or specification of worksheet name directly. For example when a relationship id is used in an attribute it is always in the same namespace.

Comment: Then I strongly recommend that you either re-post this question or, if possible, re-tag it to include tags like c++ and xlm.  This will give it more visibility to experts in these areas.